# woocommerce billing address form always appear even if the user is logged in?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-hook

I'm looking for a way to disappear woocommerce billing address in checkout page when the user is logged in. Is that possible? And in first place, Why is that?! Why billing address form is always showing in checkout page even when the user is logged in?!!!

Answer (score 1):

1) For your question one try this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    if( is_user_logged_in() ){
        unset($fields['billing']);
        $fields['billing'] = array();
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

2) For your question two :

If user wants to modify something in billing form, this is the place where he can modify nothing else. If you think this is not correct, better to develop a plugin, maybe a lot of people will be thinking this.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think if users want to change something, they could do that in my-account page not in checkout page. For example if I'm logged in and whenever I want to purchase something I see a form in front of me that I've already filled it, I really get mad!

Comment: If you want to change it for that specific purchase what you will do, you will change your my account page ?Not tested but I think changing in billing form ,does not change myacount page information. Can you tell me if the code worked ?

Comment: how could i set a default value in those fields ?

Comment: @JorgeWanderSantanaUreña You can assign values the same way you assign value to array keys.